# Notification Center: Sparrow notifications not removed automatically

Tags: macos, notifications, sparrow

Since upgrading to Mountain Lion, Sparrow (email client) places notifcations in Notification Center.

I'm happy enough with that but when I read the email in Sparrow, the notification remains in Notification Center until I manually remove it which is a pain.

- Does anyone know why?

  - Could it be on the Sparrow side not sending the API call back?
- Is there a feasible work around?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use temporary screen pop-ups, and disable the notification center:

You can set this per app.

Apple Menu -> System Preferences -> Notifications

Then, for Sparrow, choose Banners, not alerts.